# chktex not reading lines correctly

Tags: ubuntu, syntax-checker

I'm trying to use `chktex` in Ubuntu but it seems to not be reading lines correctly.
When I run it on a file that has this line (and any other line like it):

```
\include{glossary}
```

it send an error saying (note that it replaces the char before last in the file name with the last char!  - **glossayy**)

```
chktex: WARNING -- Unable to open the TeX file `glossayy'.
Warning 27 in book.tex line 158: Could not execute LaTeX command.
\include{glossary}        % Glossary   
^^^^^^^^
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: This looks like a problem with `chktex` rather than LaTeX. You're probably better off filing a bug report with the maintainer of chktex.

Answer (score 1):

Using `chktex` v1.6.4 on Ubuntu 11.04 the spelling error was not reproduced (see below). Further, this version gave the warning only when it was valid. I suggest you try this again with this version.

If the problem still occurs a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be helpful as would information as to whether the warning is just mis-spelled or also spurious (e.g. warning about files that exist).

**Detail**

Result from running on a small sample file that generates a warning but does not have a `\include` line:

```
mas@ents:~/LaTeX/scratch$ chktex fr.tex
ChkTeX v1.6.4 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann.

Warning 36 in fr.tex line 5: You should put a space in front of parenthesis.
    \textit{(Choose one option)}\\  
            ^
No errors printed; One warning printed; No user suppressed warnings printed.
```

edited test file to remedy the warning, include a `\include{glossary}` line similar to the one in the question. `glossary.tex` does not exist . Re-ran `chktex`:

```
mas@ents:~/LaTeX/scratch$ vi fr.tex
mas@ents:~/LaTeX/scratch$ chktex fr.tex
ChkTeX v1.6.4 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann.

chktex: WARNING -- Unable to open the TeX file `glossary'.
Warning 27 in fr.tex line 10: Could not execute LaTeX command.
\include{glossary}        % Glossary     
^^^^^^^^
No errors printed; One warning printed; No user suppressed warnings printed.
mas@ents:~/LaTeX/scratch$
```

warning is correct and does not include the `glossayy` text error.

With `glossary.tex` created, `chktex` returns no warnings:

```
mas@ents:~/LaTeX/scratch$ mv glossary.texxx glossary.tex
mas@ents:~/LaTeX/scratch$ chktex fr.tex
ChkTeX v1.6.4 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann.

No errors printed; No warnings printed; No user suppressed warnings printed.
mas@ents:~/LaTeX/scratch$
```

Answer (score 1):

This [was a problem](https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/index.php?34322) with calling `strcpy` on overlapping strings.  With some 
versions of glibc this caused problems and with others it didn't.  This was fixed in the svn version to use `memmove`.  I recently got svn access, so I'm hoping we can release a new version with this (and a few other bugs) fixed.  Anyway, the bottom line is that if you build it yourself form svn then it will be fixed (version is `1.6.5svn`).

Comment: I have released 1.6.6 which fixes this problem.  Of course it may take a while for it to filter down to Ubuntu.